# Is there a Notification Center widget to show more calendar information for tomorrow?

Tags: macos, calendar, notifications

I like the "idea" of the Notification Center, but it is awfully coy and so is not as useful as it might be. For example (below), it tells me I have an "event" in the afternoon but it doesn't tell me what that event is. It obviously knows what that event is but it wants to make me launch the Calendar app I guess.

Is there some setting I am missing? Or is there a plug-in which offers expanded calendar info in the sidebar?

macOS 10.11.16

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just click on edit on the bottom of the Notification Center and add the "Calendar"-widget.

It shows me full day events and six hours from now on in day view...

EDIT: Just realized you are not using Sierra... let me check on that.

2nd EDIT: Checked it on my MacPro running El Capitan OS X 10.11.6, the widget exists in the same spot (and as a bigmouth that I am, until Sierra the OSes were called OS X, and from now on macOS... not that I could've read the number you gave us :D)

3rd Edit: Oh and you did it even right when you asked originally, it was edited by a proactive moderator. Sorry for the wrong accusations. Now try it and mark it hopefully as resolved... :)

[image: It's German, sorry for that, but you get the picture :)]

Comment: Hey thanks for taking the time! I had poked around in that "edit" section before and since it looked like I already had the "Calendar" widget enabled, there wasn't much more to do. This time I removed the "Calendar" widget and then added it back in – and voila!: I get the full calendar as in your screenshot.